# Parsing a directory from address url

Tags: parsing, url

How can I parse a directory out of a url? for instance the address bar reads http://www.sample.com/directory1/directory2/index.php 
How do I get the directory2 out of it from the address bar with PHP 4?

---

here's the code I figured out. not sure how to make the "10" a variable. That's the length of the first directory. I'm unsure how to get the position of the x occurance of "\". This worked, though it is not eloquent.

```
$url=$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$end=strrpos($url,'\\', 0);
$length=$end-10;
$directory=substr($url, 10, $length);
```

Comment: What technology are you using.

Comment: PHP 4 and jQuery but want to use php

Answer (score 0):

Using PHP, check out [`parse_url()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php). Particularly the `path` key.